# ckeditor: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined (django + zinnia)

Tags: django, ckeditor, zinnia

I am experiencing this strange error only on my production environment. It works fine locally and on staging.

I'm using `Django==1.10.5` & `django-blog-zinnia==0.18.1` with `zinnia-wysiwyg-ckeditor==1.3`. I believe this issue happened recently when we upgraded from `Django==1.8` to the latest.

When I try to create a blog entry, I can't edit the content because the ckeditor instance does not load. The errors are:

`https://example.com/admin/zinnia/entry/81/change/config.js/change/ 404 (Not Found)
https://example.com/admin/zinnia/entry/81/change/lang/en.js/change/ 
GET https://example.com/admin/zinnia/entry/81/change/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css/change/ 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined`

The URL is `/admin/zinnia/entry/81/change/`

So this very much looks like ckeditor.js is trying to load additional static files based on the current URLs and somehow it injects the filenames into the current URL.

As a workaround, I ssh-ed into the server and manipulated `/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.8bd276b5ef4c.js` and added this line at the very top:

`window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/';`

This solves the issue. The big question is: Why does this only happen on one of my machines, why does Django/zinnia not set `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` correctly by itself?

I'm posting this here because I am not sure if this is an issue in Django, zinnia or zinnia-ckeditor, if anyone got insights on who is guilty, I'm happy to re-post this issue on the relevant issue tracker on github.

EDIT:

As a workaround, in my project I created the file `templates/admin/change_form.html`:

> `{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}`
>
> `{% block extrahead %}`
>
> `<script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/';</script>`
>
> `{{ block.super }}`
>
> `{% endblock %}`